# Wordpress taking too long to post until timeout

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog with about 33000 posts and the database is about 2.2gb. The speed of the blog is very fast except when i try to post or update any post.. It will run for minutes until timeout but the process continues to run in the background at 100% cpu. I am wondering if there is any workaround? I am sure there are wp can handle alot more posts and a bigger database without such issue.

Comment: Why is the database that large, are you storing images in the database?

Comment: I had timeouts in my Wordpress blog until I disabled one of the plugins that wasn't working right.  I think it was the LiveJournal Crossposter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your post/page revisions. WordPress saves a full copy of each post as a revision file upon saves. That will drop the size of your database drastically - I've reduced databases to 10% of their original sizes - with a subsequent increase in performance. See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-delete-revision/

Or run this query in phpmyadmin:

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'revision'
```

Add `define ('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 0);` to the wp-config.php file to prevent future revisions from being saved.

If you have your own server, look into using mysqltuner.pl to analyze the MySQL database server and loads and be able to adjust your my.cnf file for better performance. See https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl

*Also look for other non-WP tables in the database that are large.* Some web stats plugins write logs to the database, and those tables can get huge. Even if not in use, such large tables can impact performance. Deactivate/delete the plugins to clear and tables, or clear the tables manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've got ~14100 posts in the wp_posts table on a site I manage. The DB is ~102MB. Using that as a reference your DB should be 240MB or so. Why is your DB so large?

If the problem occurs when you post, chances are that you've got a plugin that is trying to do a tremendous amount of work (possibly why your DB is so large), or maybe that is trying to contact a third party site, and is timing out. Check your plugins. Disable them one by one if it isn't obvious where the problem is.

Answer (score -2):

Use this.  Problem Solved.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/

Tested on a server with over 500K unique users per month.